# How can I use SSHJ to stream a file via SCP?

Tags: java, ssh, scp, sshj

I am using the SSHJ library (https://github.com/shikhar/sshj).

I can use `sshClient.newSCPFileTransfer();` to get my `SCPClient` object, but then the call to `scpClient.download()` requires either a String as the path for the destination file or a LocalDestFile object. All I want is to open a stream to download the file to. Is there a way to easily do this using SSHJ?

I looked at the different implementations of LocalDestFile, but nothing seemed applicable to this use case.

The specific use case is downloading a remote file and streaming it to a client's browser for a web app. I have to use SCP for this and thus want to use the SSHJ library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by extending the `InMemoryDestFile` class and passing my desired `OutputStream` object into the constructor and having it returned in the `getOutputStream` method.

An example is shown in the following GIST: https://gist.github.com/2157565

It seems that you need to close the `OutputStream` on your own when you are done, so watch out for that.